# Solution - Error during composer global require laravel/installer

Tags: laravel

For anyone who will encounter/encountering something similar to this and tried everything else like `composer global update`, `global remove and install`, or even the `composer require laravel/installer:*` command.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - symfony/process[v4.2.0, ..., v4.4.10] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/process[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.8] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/installer v4.2.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/installer ^4.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v4.2.0, ..., v4.2.10].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v5.3.14 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v2.8.52 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v5.4.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/homestead ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/homestead[v2.0.0, ..., v2.2.2].
    - laravel/installer[v4.2.0, ..., v4.2.9] require symfony/process ^4.2|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.2.0, ..., v4.4.37, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.3].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: symfony/process[2.0.4, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.2.0, ..., v4.4.37, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.3, v6.0.0, v6.0.2, v6.0.3].
    - laravel/homestead[v2.0.0, ..., v2.2.1] require symfony/process ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[2.0.4, ..., v2.8.52].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v2.6.13 (conflict analysis result)

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/installer:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/installer:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

or the other preceeding error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v4.0.0 requires php ^7.2.9 -> your php version (8.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/installer[v4.0.1, ..., v4.0.7] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/installer[v4.1.0, ..., v4.2.9] require symfony/console ^4.0|^5.0 -> found symfony/console[v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.37, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.3] but the package is fixed to v3.4.47 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - laravel/installer v4.2.10 requires symfony/console ^4.0|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/console[v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.37, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.3, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3] but the package is fixed to v3.4.47 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/installer ^4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v4.0.0, ..., v4.2.10].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit in my problem is the `laravel/homestead:v2.0` which requires lower version of everything else which conflicts with the higher version the `laravel/installer` requires.

I edited my `composer.json`, removed everything except the `codesniffer` and required the latest laravel/installer version and it should install smoothly. The whole process did not install the `laravel/homestead` automatically so I also manually required it and it ended up looking like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6",
        "symfony/console": "v6.0.3",
        "laravel/installer": "4.2.10",
        "laravel/homestead": "^13.2"
    }
}
```

Your laravel/installer should now work fine. And the `laravel new project-name` command should working as intended.

PS: Your `composer.json` location would be shown in the terminal but just in case, the default path would be:

> C:/Users/{Your user name}/AppData/Roaming/Composer